# How to approximate a line from points

Tags: c#, math, 2d, linear-algebra

I'm looking for a simple implementation of total least squares.

Or any other way to approximate a line from a set of points that doesn't discriminate between the x- and y-axes.

I have been able to find some scientific papers about it, but since it seems to be such a simple and common problem, I thought that there would be some good library or example code available somewhere.

I will have to write this in C#, but I can translate from similar languages.

[image: total least squares]

Comment: Actually... my data points have independent velocities... so if it's not veeery complicated, I would like to minimize the distance along their velocities.
(Feel free to ignore this info if it complicates everything too much.)

Comment: I don't have any code, because I haven't yet understood the problem fully.
I watched through this whole series, https://www.khanacademy.org/math/linear-algebra/alternate-bases/orthogonal-projections/v/linear-algebra-least-squares-approximation but he doesn't explain how to use this method for the 2D problem in total least squares.

Comment: i think [this](http://csharphelper.com/blog/2014/10/find-a-linear-least-squares-fit-for-a-set-of-points-in-c/) can help you

Comment: the problem is that here it's based on y being expressed as a function of x, which means that the method behaves differently if my points have the same x value

Comment: well of course, that not a problem that how math works if y = x ^ 2, then it's obvious that y will be different for every x

Comment: LSQ for y(x) with vertical offsets is widely used because (1) it is suitable for functions and (2) it is described with very simple formulas, suitable for handle-made and computer calculations. Using perpendicular offsets (Orthogonal Distance Regression) requires general line equation like `|x*cos(f)+y*sin(f)+c|=distance` and equation system becomes more, more complex (try to make squared and get partial differentials by f and c)

Comment: [This answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/136597/143190) might help. Principal component analysis seems sufficient to solve the problem. There surely are some PCA libraries for C#, though I don't know enough C# to mention any (and asking for library recommendations are off-topic anyways).

Comment: @JohnColeman thanks. I will study this and see if I manage to get the correct intuition from it.

Answer (score 0):

Wikipedia lists a simple calculation for the approximation
in the picture.

[Deming regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deming_regression)

The problem is still treated as 1D, so it's necessary to handle the special
case of a vertical line. Swapping x for y resolves this.

Using a δ of 1 is totally fine since we're only looking for minimizing the euclidean distance to the line.

**Note:** The equation also breaks down for horizontal lines. Then S<sub>xy</sub> will be zero.

Comment: Wiki page contains link to Coolidge paper. It considers approach that I have written in comment and uses very clever method to simplify things.